# laravel 5 search query issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need to search filtering different columns from DB table, those filtering columns are groupA, groupb and groupC, each column has one of following values `high, low, moderate` in db table

But front end user have anther value called "none", but that value is not contain in database.

This is my current query

```
  public function show($groupA, $groupB, $groupC)
    {
        $FodMaps = FodMap::where('groupA', '=', $groupA)->where('groupB', '=', $groupB)->where('groupC', '=', $groupC)->get();
        return $FodMaps;


    }
```

What I want is if user search with value which does not contain in db (high/low/moderate) it should search the other columns except the one which have unmatching values

ex: http://url/api/fodmap/groupA=low/groupB=low/groupC=high

if user enter above way it should display the results according to the values

but if user inputs like following

http://url/api/fodmap/groupA=low/groupB=low/groupC=none

since "none" value in groupC column does not exit it should search only other two columns without considering the value of groupC

please advice

Answer (score 0):

You can add query condition dynamically like this.

```
    public function show($groupA, $groupB, $groupC)
    {
        $query = FodMap::query();
        if ($groupA !== 'none') {
          $query->where('groupA', '=', $groupA)
        }

        if ($groupB !== 'none') {
          $query->where('groupB', '=', $groupB)
        }

        if ($groupC !== 'none') {
          $query->where('groupC', '=', $groupC)
        }

        return $query->get();
    }
```